# How do I extract Microsoft SQL varbinary(max) field to image using golang?

Tags: sql-server, go

I have a varbinary(max) field in Microsoft SQL Server which contains an image.

When running "SELECT IMAGE FROM TABLE", I get a result which looks like "0x07FD30...."

When using go to retrieve the data, I get the same hex string which is stored as a []byte:

```
type Person struct {
    PersonID string
    Image    []byte
}
```

I connect to the database and do:

```
rows.Scan(&person.PersonID, &person.Image)
```

And then print the result as hex, it's the same:

```
fmt.Printf("%#x", p.Image)
```

Result:

```
0x07fd30...
```

My question is, how do I turn this back into an image?

I've tried writing the raw bytes to a file:

```
ioutil.WriteFile("./tempfile.png", p.Image, 0644)
```

I've tried using the image library to decode it, which just errors with an unidentified kind:

```
image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(p.Image))
```

And also tried `png.Encode` too.

Any thoughts or pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've tried writing the raw bytes to a file" - what happened? "And also tried png.Encode too." - hopefully you tried to *de*code, not *en*code, but again, what happened? And what is your end goal? When you say "turn this back into an image", what does that mean? If the bytes are encoded image data, it already *is* an image, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's what I thought -- I assumed that the data I received from SQL would just be encoded image data. The file wasn't an image unfortunately.  My end goal is to save the images elsewhere as part of a process we have.  I suppose the question is, is my assumption correct?  Or am I incorrect to take the data into a []byte and just write it out?

Comment: If you take a file, read all of its bytes, store them in a database, read all the bytes back out, and write them to a file, you've effectively just copied the file. If the original was a valid image, the copy will be a valid image.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That's my assumption too, but clearly I'm wrong as it doesn't appear to be working.  Based on that, one would have to assume that the original data isn't a straight image.  If it helps, the image is placed there by Microsoft Dynamics.

Comment: "it doesn't appear to be working" *meaning what*? Can you clarify the points from my original comment? It's not clear what issues you're actually running into here.

Comment: The reason for asking the question is to understand if what I am doing is correct.  I am trying to extract images from a database.  The images are stored in a varbinary(max) field.  I'm using "database/sql" and "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" to retrieve the data from SQL.  When I say it doesn't appear to work, what I mean is that when I take the data from the IMAGE field into a []byte and write that to a file, the resulting file is NOT an image.

Comment: With regards png.Decode and jpeg.Decode, I get the errors `png: invalid format: not a PNG file` and `invalid JPEG format: missing SOI marker` respectively.

Comment: What does you mean "the resulting file is not an image"? By what metric? If you're trying both png and jpeg encoders, does that mean you don't know what format the image data is in?

Comment: It will definitely be one of those formats.  That's why I used image.Decode originally to see if it would identify the type.  I'm going to change one of the images now so that I can guarantee what type it is, but I suspect that I'll have the same results.  In terms of "by what metric", I cannot view the resulting file as an image with my eyes?

Comment: Your eyes can't decode a compressed image byte stream into its image representation unless you're a savant. What are you using to determine if if the written file is a valid image?

Comment: Lol.  I'm double clicking on it to open it in an image viewer which says the file format is not supported.

Comment: Verify that the source data being written to the database is actually a complete, valid image file in one of those formats.

Comment: How do you propose I do that?  Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea, it's your data source. I can tell you that if you take all the bytes in the database and write them to a file, and that file isn't valid, then whatever is writing those bytes to the database is either doing something wrong, or isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I guess that's what I needed confirmation on, that my assumptions were correct.  I'm taking a look into how the data is written to the database.  Being dynamics, it's not exactly straight forward, but I think that's where I need to look now.  Thanks again.

Comment: What's odd is that if I run "strings" on the resulting file, I see exif and RDF data in there which would imply it's an image file.  Goodness knows what Microsoft is doing to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the raw bytes to a file with `ioutil.WriteFile("./tempfile.png", p.Image, 0644)` does seem to be the correct process.  However, for whatever reason, Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 seems to add an extra 7 bytes to the beginning of the file when saving it to the database with their BinData class. So, using `ioutil.WriteFile(s, p.Image[7:], 0644)` works.  I'd like to understand what those 7 bytes are and what they're for, but that's for another day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Darren was correct about the first 7 bytes always get added to the image files by AX, that is `07FD3097F90000`. 
Unfortunately, it seems that AX also adds other information to the end of the binary file. I haven't figured out the exact pattern of the that but typically if the uploaded image is .png, AX just adds `FF` to the end, otherwise it makes tons of changes to the file.

In your case, if you are just interested in one specific image stored in SQL server, take a look at the binary file and see if it's ended with `FF`. If yes, strip off the extra bytes and then convert it to base64 to display it.

```
var data="0xFFD8FFE000104A464946....d";

var bytes = [];

for(var i=2; i< data.length-1; i+=2){
    bytes.push(parseInt(data.substr(i, 2), 16));
}
//str contains the base64 form of the image
var str = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes));
```